# How to join and echo 2 different MongoDB collections using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to `join` and `echo` 2 different MongoDB collections using PHP?

in MYSQL(Using PHP)

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT U.username, P.post FROM users U, posts P WHERE u.user_id=p.user_id_fk") or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo $result['username'];
 echo $result['post'];
}
```

in MongoDB(Using PHP)
???

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support joins. Also, it's been asked on StackOverflow before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829638/mongodb-php-how-to-do-inner-join-like-query

Comment: then how to keep to have 2 collection and get the information from two collection? does it use mapreduce?

Comment: Write two queries. The driver may be able to do this automatically, but it's not really a join, it's just lazy loading if it works.