# MongoDB JOIN like SQL Server

Tags: mongodb, join, subquery

How to write a JOIN query like this one in MongoDB form?

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, TABLE2.MOBILE_PHONE
FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
WHERE TABLE1.NUMBER IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform the SQL Join equivalent in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb)

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829638/mongodb-php-how-to-do-inner-join-like-query

Comment: Those topics do not have resolution answers.

Comment: You expect a resolution answer by asking the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, a friend of mine helped me building a query that in some way gave me what I needed.

Example:

db.table1.find({number: {$in: ['1','2','3']}}, {id: 1,'table2.mobile_phone': 1});

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo 3.2 the `$lookup` parameters was introduced, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "othercollection",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
         as: "inventory_docs"
        }
    }
 ])
```

For the moment the `$lookup` operator is only available in the aggregation framework and you may run into problems if you try use to join big collections.
Alternatively you can join the data at application level. You would basically run two find queries and combine the results by joining them on the relevant keys.